# Line color in plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I change the color of line with function plot , I used this code to plot a line:

```
imshow(fnnMiddleLine)
hold on
plot([TLx , BRx ],[TLy ,BRy],'-', 'MarkerEdgeColor' , 'k' ,'MarkerFaceColor' , 'y')
hold off
```

But it always come with blue line even when I change the value to other colour. I have tried many times and reading here but I couldn't find the answer... Please any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
imshow(fnnMiddleLine)
hold on
plot([TLx , BRx ],[TLy ,BRy],'-k', 'MarkerEdgeColor' , 'k' ,'MarkerFaceColor' , 'y')
hold off
```

It will plot black lines. The trick is one more identifier '-k'. Run

```
help plot
```

to get more color options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `'Color'` property:

```
plot(1:10,'-', 'color','red')
```

The values for the color property can be strings like `'red'` or RGB values like `[1, 0, 0]`.  Check out the [doc page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#namevaluepairarguments) for more information.

You can also embed this information in the linespec argument like Daniel showed.